# What's beneficial about temporal auto Bezier keyframes over continuous Bezier keyframes?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, animation, motion, keyframes

From what understand, a temporal auto Bezier keyframe automatically re-adjusts both of its direction handles whenever a neighboring keyframe is moved somehow and the influences of both of its incoming and outgoing velocities are always the same. Whereas a temporal continuous Bezier keyframe does not re-adjusts at all, and the influences are different. So those are the differences on how they work.

But what are the real benefits of auto Bezier keyframes over continuous Bezier keyframes? Most of the time, as far as I know, most people use Easy Ease (In/Out) keyframe assistants anyway, and end up manually adjusting the curves, which results only in continuous Bezier keyframes. What's the point of auto Bezier keyframes?